# Что использовать для реализации сервиса, работающего в режиме ожидания?

Tags: android, android-service

Пишу приложение, которое будет показывать уведомления. Вообщем, нужно написать сервис который будет их показывать **когда экран заблокирован**. А также **когда приложение закрыто**. Как гуглить даже не пойму. background service если искать, то нахожу про простые сервисы. А мне нужен непростой. ВК же как-то отправляет их

Comment: Это вообще возможно сделать быстро? Я нигде ничего найти не могу, это что, запрещено? Если делать значит юзать дыры в системе? Складывается такое ощущение

Comment: Вы пробовали AlarmManager вместо сервиса использовать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, уже читаю. Но не пойму как его использовать. Мне надо каждые 2 минуты делать сетевой запрос и если ответ соответствует форме, то показать уведомление. С `AlarmManager` такое можно провернуть? А

Comment: В теории вы создаёте очередь задач. Когда придёт время всплывет интент, его поймает ваш ресивер и там можно что-то кодом сделать. Но как оно будет в условиях спящего телефона работать - не знаю, т.к. не пробовал и не читал

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я же говорю - никто не делал это. Ни на so ничего нет, ни на гитхабе, даже либ нет. Я поражаюсь.

Comment: Ну, значит вы можете первым быть) А ВК, например, свои уведомления наверняка пушами шлёт. Т.е. никаких сервисов и прочего, всё через гугловый FireBase. Но для этого сервер свой нужен с логикой всякой и т.д.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ого, а можно поконкретнее? Я как раз в паре с веб прогиаммистом, он сервер делает.

Comment: Ну, просто берёте доку к FireBase и пилите получение/отпраку пушей. Но никто вам, конечно, не даст гарантии что они будут прямо всегда и в любом состоянии телефона приходить. Но так, по крайней мере, меньше на клиенте кода (и больше на сервере)

Comment: ВК скорее всего отправляет пуш с high priority, что позволяет пробиться через Doze Mode и отобразить уведомление

Comment: Да там все настраивается прям в консоле FireBase, если что можно допилить свой Broadcast, который будет выдергивать из любого состояния.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei каким образам пробьется ваш допиленный Broadcast через DozeMode?

Comment: @tim_taller, ну так выходит, значит только Firebase? Ничего не надо поверх этого пилить?

Comment: @Flippy Firebase это платформа для настройки и отправки пушей. настройте отправку пушей с high priority

Comment: @tim_taller, а на стороне клиента что делать? В доках не поймеу ничего. Живой пример есть? ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Синхроинизация вам не подойдет? https://habrahabr.ru/company/e-Legion/blog/216857/

Comment: Статья в чулане и вообще это не то